# How to drop dataframe rows if they match an item in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows if the value in a column matches an item in a list. I tried:

```
bets.drop(bets[bets["id_"] in bet_ids].index, inplace=True)
```

However, I got the error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried adding `any()`:

```
bets.drop(bets[any(bets["id_"] in bet_ids)].index, inplace=True)
```

But get the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do with `isin`

```
bets.drop(bets.index[bets["id_"].isin(bet_ids)], inplace=True)
```